# Difference between Python and Java for Base64 decode

Tags: java, python

### Here is a python code version:

```
 def decode(s):
  for i in range(len(s)):
      print compat_ord(s[i])

def compat_ord(c):
    if type(c) is int:
        return c
    else:
        return ord(c)
decode(base64.b64decode('NwXYSw8YI7nb2PnE8eJxVoLzuBQ81wjOXh4='.encode('ascii')))
```

### output

> 55
>   5
>   216
>   75
>   15
>   24
>   35
>   185
>   219
>   216
>   249
>   196
>   241
>   226
>   113
>   86
>   130
>   243
>   184
>   20
>   60
>   215
>   8
>   206
>   94
>   30

### My Java Version

```
byte[] s = Base64.getDecoder().decode("NwXYSw8YI7nb2PnE8eJxVoLzuBQ81wjOXh4=".getBytes("ascii"));
for(int i= 0;i<s.length;i++){
  System.out.println(s[i]);
}
```

### Ouptput

> 55
>   5
>   -40
>   75
>   15
>   24
>   35
>   -71
>   -37
>   -40
>   -7
>   -60
>   -15
>   -30
>   113
>   86
>   -126
>   -13
>   -72
>   20
>   60
>   -41
>   8
>   -50
>   94
>   30

### My Question

Why some values are same while some are not

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`byte` in Java is 8 bit signed. So you will get negative values.

Change

```
System.out.println(s[i]);
```

to

```
System.out.println(s[i]&0xff);
```

to get the same values.

Update: I just saw that Java 8 introduced [Byte.toUnsignedInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#toUnsignedInt-byte-). This is perhaps more readable:

```
System.out.println(Byte.toUnsignedInt(s[i]));
```

Comment: is it possible the result of the decrypting of the bytes would be same?